# Image upload error, unable to upload images in magento 2

Tags: magento2, image, upload

[image: Image upload failed in Magento 2]

Need a solution tried checking uploader.php for file extension MIME type.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MGS\Lookbook\Controller\Adminhtml\Lookbook;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Upload extends \MGS\Lookbook\Controller\Adminhtml\Lookbook
{
    protected $uploader;

    private $allowedExtensions = array();
    private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
    private $min_image_width = 0;
    private $min_image_height = 0;
    private $max_image_width = 0;
    private $max_image_height = 0;    
    private $filemodel;

    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $uploadXhr;
    protected $uploadfileForm;
    protected $helper;
    protected $_file;
    protected $_imageFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, 
        \MGS\Lookbook\Model\Uploadedfilexhr $uploadXhr,
        \MGS\Lookbook\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $file,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,
        \MGS\Lookbook\Model\Uploadedfileform $uploadfileForm
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->uploadXhr = $uploadXhr;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->_file = $file;
        $this->uploadfileForm = $uploadfileForm;
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;

        $sizeLimit = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('lookbook/general/max_upload_filesize');
        $this->min_image_width = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('lookbook/general/min_image_width');
        $this->min_image_height = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('lookbook/general/min_image_height');
        $this->max_image_width = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('lookbook/general/max_image_width');
        $this->max_image_height = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('lookbook/general/max_image_height');
        $allowed_extensions = explode(',',$this->scopeConfig->getValue('lookbook/general/allowed_extensions'));

        $this->allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowed_extensions);
        if ($sizeLimit>0) $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;      

        if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
            $this->filemodel = $this->uploadXhr;
        } elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
            $this->filemodel = $this->uploadfileForm;
        } else {
            $this->filemodel = false; 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $upload_dir = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('lookbook/');

        $config_check = $this->checkServerSettings();

        if($config_check === true){
           $result = $this->handleUpload($upload_dir); 
        } 
        else
        {
            $result = $config_check;
        }

        // to pass data through iframe you will need to encode all html tags
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES));
    }

    function parse_size($size) {
        $unit = preg_replace('/[^bkmgtpezy]/i', '', $size); // Remove the non-unit characters from the size.
        $size = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', '', $size); // Remove the non-numeric characters from the size.
        if ($unit) {
        // Find the position of the unit in the ordered string which is the power of magnitude to multiply a kilobyte by.
            return round($size * pow(1024, stripos('bkmgtpezy', $unit[0])));
        }
        else {
            return round($size);
        }
    }

    public function checkServerSettings(){    
        $postSize = $this->parse_size($this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size')));
        $uploadSize = $this->parse_size($this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')));        

        if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
            $size = max(100, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';             
            return array('error' => 'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size');    
        }

        if ($this->max_image_width < $this->min_image_width || $this->max_image_height < $this->min_image_height){            
            return array('error' => 'File was not uploaded. Minimal image width (height) can\'t be greater then maximal. Please, check settings.');    
        }
        return true; 

    }

    private function toBytes($str){
        $val = trim($str);
        $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
        switch($last) {
            case 'g': $val *= 1024;
            case 'm': $val *= 1024;
            case 'k': $val *= 1024;        
        }
        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
     */
 function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = FALSE){
        if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
            return array('error' => "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable.");
        }

        if (!$this->filemodel){
            return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
        }

        $size = $this->filemodel->getSize();

        if ($size == 0) {
            return array('error' => 'File is empty');
        }

        if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
            return array('error' => 'File is too large');
        }

        $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->filemodel->getName());
        $filename = $pathinfo['filename'];
        //$filename = md5(uniqid());
        $filename = uniqid();
        $ext = $pathinfo['extension'];

        if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
            $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
            return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
        }

        if(!$replaceOldFile){
            /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
            while ($this->_file->isExists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
                $filename .= rand(10, 99);
            }
        }

        if ($this->filemodel->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){  
            $imgPathFull = $uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext;
            $dimensions = $this->helper->getImageDimensions($imgPathFull);
             if ($this->min_image_width!=0 && $this->min_image_height!=0) {
                if ($dimensions['width'] < $this->min_image_width || $dimensions['height'] < $this->min_image_height)
                {
                   $this->_file->deleteFile($imgPathFull);
                   return array('error'=> 'Uploaded file dimensions are less than those specified in the configuration.');
                }                                                        
             }

            if ($this->max_image_width!=0 && $this->max_image_height!=0) {
                if ($dimensions['width'] > $this->max_image_width || $dimensions['height'] > $this->max_image_height)
                {
                    $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
                    $imageResize->open($imgPathFull);
                    $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
                    $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);
                    $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
                    $imageResize->resize($this->max_image_width,$this->max_image_height);  

                    //save image      
                    $imageResize->save($imgPathFull);
                    $dimensions = $this->helper->getImageDimensions($imgPathFull);
                }
            }
            return array('success'=>true, 'filename'=>$filename . '.' . $ext, 'dimensions' => $dimensions);
        } else {
            return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
                'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: please attached your code